# Efficient way to set up a persistent read-only dictionary with many keys but simple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, nosql

I have roughly 100k (fairly short) unicode strings and for each of them a corresponding integer.

I need to store them in a dicionary-like persistent object that will be then accessed only for reading.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't fill the ram loading the whole structure and not too much greedy of space on disk.

I already tried [dbm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dbm.html) and [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), but I got a resulting file of 30Mb+.

I'm sure there are tools which fits better on this specific case, so any pointers (for both python2 or python3) are welcome.

Comment: can't you just zip the shelved file and unzip it while loading?

Comment: If you're only mapping a string to an integer a list of tupels first comes to my mind (`[("ddfsdf", 1231), ("asdfasdf", 52399), ...]`). Its probably faster to (de-)serialize into a ASCII or binary format and even looking up items could be as fast as a dictionary when sorting the list.

Comment: Can you post representative examples?

Comment: @try-catch-finally as I said, I'd prefer to avoid loading the whole dataset in ram every time I have to pick a value.

Comment: @User you can take as examples the ones given by try-catch-finally in his comment, the keys are basically unicode strings of a length between ~3-15 chars and the values are integers with at most nine digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Index**
You may want to build an index.

The database is a file with each string in a line(or other dividing character)and the number at the end of the line.
The strings are sorted.
You can do binary search.
You can use merge sort to build the structure. Merge two index files into one.

The cost:

`O(n*log(n))` writes of each mapping during the creation
`O(log(n))` lookups during search (lots of searches take long on a spinning disk)
`O(max_string_length)` memory usage

We built such a thing in Java for a Search Engine Seminar. It can grow to gigabytes and still answer fast. In this context it is called an [inverted index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).

**directory structure**
You can create a directory for the string and in this directory a string with the  number as its name. If you are lucky, it will not take 4kb for each entry. I do not know.

Comment: Both solutions are extremely interessant. I like the idea of using the filesystem as database, and probably I'll do that. I have to figure out a way to encode illegal characters though (e.g. "/").

Comment: You can use [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64): `base64.b64encode(u'\u0436'.encode('UTF-8')).replace('/', '_') ==
 b'0LY='` and hashlib - if you want fixed sizes.